# Exporting tracking codes across multiple Google Analytics accounts

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I was looking to generate a report or export Tracking Codes across multiple accounts in GA. Was wondering if this would be possible.

For example, account 1 has mobile app, iPad app. Account 2 has mobile app, web app. Would it be possible to generate a table that outputs something like this:

```
Account | Property | Tracking Code
account 1 | mobile app | abc
account 1 | iPad app | xyz
account 2 | mobile app | hij
account 2 | web app | def
```